# Problem on Joomla Framework Sample Application Setup

Tags: joomla-framework-1.x

I have cloned [Framework Sample Application](https://github.com/dbhurley/framework-app). Updated using **composer**, everything worked fine. Got this welcome screen which congratulates saying **installation is completed.**
[image]

But when i enter my **db_credentials** to update setting and click **update database link**.
[image]

> it gives me **not found page**.

[image]

> Am i missing some **steps** here ?

Comment: Seems that there is some bug in the application. When you click on this link it should execute `updateDatabase()` in `/App/Controller/DashboardController.php`, but it seems that something goes wrong.

Comment: I noticed that. Can we do something to fix that?

Comment: I need to take a closer look on it. Currently I even do not have a setup of this App :) Or you can try to fix it and submit pull request. Of course if it is a bug. Currently I am not sure.

Comment: So I installed the app and it works fine for me. Probably you should adjust something. May be you installed it in subfolder?

Comment: Thanks for your decent effort for identifying problem in my config. It indeed was in a sub-folder, and i solved it. Please write answer so that i can accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have installed it in the subfolder.

In case Bootstrap is not working you should copy `css`, `js` and `img` folders from `/vendor/twbs/docs`.